# How to add material-ui component by innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm rookie to React and StackOverflow

I've been trying to add an Button component with material-ui by using document.getElementById.innerHTML.

But when the button come out, the material-ui does not work.
Does anyone know how to append the component with material-ui applied successfully?
Here's my code, thanks a lot!

```
class CRUD extends Component {
state = {
    switchStatus: false,
    users: [],
    table: [],
    findOneTime: false,
}
switch = () => {
    this.setState({
        switchStatus: !this.state.switchStatus,
    })
}
allUser = () => {
    if (this.state.findOneTime === true)
        return null;
    axios({
        method: "GET",
        baseURL: "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/em",
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Method": "GET",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Accept: "application/json"
        }
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        if (response && response.data) {
            this.setState({
                users: response.data,
            })
            this.state.table.push(<Button variant='outlined' color='info' onClick={this.allUser}>Edit</Button>)
            document.getElementById('tableBody').innerHTML +=
                response.data.map(item => {
                    return (
                        `   <tr>
                                <td>${item.userId}</td>
                                <td>${item.userName}</td>
                                <td>${item.userPassword}</td>
                                <td>${item.userEmail}</td>
////////////////////////////These two button's css does not work//////////////////////////////////

                                <td colSpan='2'><Button variant='outlined' color='info' onClick={this.allUser}>Edit</Button></td>
                                <td colSpan='2'><Button variant='outlined' color='error' onClick={this.switch}>Delete</Button></td>

////////////////////////////These two button's css does not work//////////////////////////////////

                            </tr>
                        `
                    )
                }).join('')
            this.setState({
                findOneTime: true,
            })
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}
render() {
     return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <h1 align='center'>User detail</h1>
                <table align='center' width='800'>
                    <thead align='center' style={{ fontSize: '20px', color: 'darkorange' }}>
                        <tr align='center'>
                            <td>UserID</td>
                            <td>Name</td>
                            <td>Password</td>
                            <td>Email</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id='tableBody' style={{ display: this.state.switchStatus ? 'none' : '' }} align='center'>

                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr align='center'>
                            <td colSpan='2'><Button variant='outlined' color='info' onClick={this.allUser}>Find</Button></td>
                            <td colSpan='2'><Button variant='outlined' color='error' onClick={this.switch}>Switch</Button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

| **Before clicking** |
| --- |
| [image] |
| **After clicking** |
| [image] |

Comment: You can't mix React with native DOM methods like that. You should really take [another look at how React works](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html).

Comment: @Andy Thank u for ur advise!I'll take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.innerHTML` expects HTML code, but React is not HTML, it is Javascript and JSX, and JSX is Javascript with a HTML like syntax (but not real HTML).

You generally should never use DOM methods and properties like `document.getElementById()` or `.innerHTML` in React (you *can* do in some cases, but you pretty much never should).

Your can just put the `<tr>` loop inside the `<tbody>` like this:

```
<tbody id='tableBody' ...>
    { this.state.users.map(item => {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{ item.userId }</td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
</tbody>
```

Generally you should try and separate your code into

1. building up some state, containing pure data, like inside your `.then( response => this.setState(...); )`, and
2. render the JSX according to the state (inside the `render()` method), like my example above with the `<tbody>`.

Comment: Thank u so much! I'll change the way to generate new components in React way!